# How to prevent the dialog after accepting Next Best Action?

Tags: visual-workflow, einstein-next-best-action

After clicking Accept on a Next Best Action, this dialog pops up:

[image]

I do not want this, I just want the quoted flow to execute without bothering the user.
How can I arrange that?